# How to convert HTML <h3> </h3> to MS document Heading3 in Docx4j?

Tags: java, docx4j, tableofcontents

I've been generating word document from HTML content.

using below code.

```
ordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(PageSizePaper.LETTER, false);

XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
XHTMLImporter.setRunFormatting(FormattingOption.CLASS_PLUS_OTHER);
NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert("<h3> SAMPLE HEADING</h3>", null));

File exportFile = new File(somepath/sample.docx);
wordMLPackage.save(exportFile);
```

Above code works fine and generate the Document, but the HTML `<h3> SAMPLE HEADING</h3>` doesn't converted to MS word **Heading 3** it shows as Normal text in document.

Later I'll generate Table of Content **TOC** using those headings using below code.

```
tocGenerator.generateToc( 1,    "TOC \\o \"1-3\" \\h \\z \\u ", false);
```

However some how this code doesn't support normal text to generate TOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to change the Heading setting by using below code.

```
ImportXHTMLProperties.setProperty("docx4j-ImportXHTML.Element.Heading.MapToStyle", true);
```

Here the updated code which is working for the requirement.

```
//  activating Headings property for MS Word Heading Mapping
ImportXHTMLProperties.setProperty("docx4j-ImportXHTML.Element.Heading.MapToStyle", true);
ordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(PageSizePaper.LETTER, false);

XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
XHTMLImporter.setRunFormatting(FormattingOption.CLASS_PLUS_OTHER);
NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert("<h3> SAMPLE HEADING</h3>", null));

File exportFile = new File(somepath/sample.docx);
// adding TOC - TABLE OF CONTENTS
TocGenerator tocGenerator = new TocGenerator(wordMLPackage);
tocGenerator.generateToc(0, "TOC \\o \"1-3\" \\h \\z \\u ", false);

wordMLPackage.save(exportFile);
```